# Â£ on an input[type=text]

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, character-encoding

I have some jQuery setting the value on an `input[type=text]` like so:

```
if(theVal=="EPC/Floorplan"){
    $('#s3').val("£100.00").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').hide();
}else if(theVal=="EPC"){
    $('#s3').val("£75.00").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').hide();
}else{
    $('#s3').val("£0.00").removeAttr("disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').show();
}
```

However the input then looks like so:

[image: Input with £]

I also have the following metatag:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

[Here's the site in question. Click any option on the dropdown](http://www.cxggroup.co.uk/payment/)

Comment: Tried to mimic your content type and mine works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsHzc/6/

Comment: Are you sure your server also serves a UTF-8 encoded file? Stating it in the meta tags is only a hint.

Comment: @Jivings - see antyrats answer - jsfiddle will do the js with the html page's encoding

Comment: @m90 - see antyrats answer as well, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `charset` attribute to included script:

```
<script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unicode:

```
\u00A3
```

In your example:

```
if(theVal=="EPC/Floorplan"){
    $('#s3').val("\u00A3" + "100.00").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').hide();
}else if(theVal=="EPC"){
    $('#s3').val("\u00A3" + "75.00").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').hide();
}else{
    $('#s3').val("\u00A3" + "0.00").removeAttr("disabled");
    $('.priceUpdate button').show();
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly as well, however I will accept antyrats answer as it is more "global", and avoids me having to replace every instance of `£`

Answer (score 1):

Your server is already providing a `Content-Type` header with an encoding set to `ISO-8859-1`. The browser will only take your `<meta>` element into account if the server does not provide that header itself.

Here is the relevant part of the Firebug trace:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 14:19:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Try to configure your server (or your server-side code) so it sets the `UTF-8` content encoding instead.

Comment: another perfectly viable answer, however I would not wish to cause conflict with other sites on the shared server that use ISO-8859-1